# How to minimize load time of JavaVM when a jar is called from Python?

Tags: java, python, google-closure-compiler

I'm using the [Google Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app) jar file to minimize production JS files that reflect changes done by my clients. Every time a user click "Publish Changes" on the back end panel, it creates a system call to compiler.jar file - but every such call takes 4-6 seconds, regardless of the JS file size. After research I found that most of the delay is to load the JavaVM for each and every call. System is Ubuntu and Python.

How can I keep the JavaVM constantly up and running and make it load the compiler.jar file every time a user click "Publish"?

Python code:

```
import subprocess
jarjs = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, "compiler.jar")
fn_output = fn_source.replace('.js','.min.js')
p = subprocess.Popen(['java','-jar',jarjs,'--jscomp_off','internetExplorerChecks','--compilation_level','SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS','--js',fn_source,'--js_output_file',fn_output], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

[fuller code](http://plnkr.co/edit/3jqXhnp0pweCRAdWnBPv?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

There are several generic solutions for java that keep processes loaded including:

http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/

and

https://github.com/ninjudd/drip

Update Sept. 2018: It is also now possible to build the Closure Compiler with the Graal `native-image` tool.  This provides amazingly faster startup, but lower peak performance.  For anything that build in under 30s in the JVM version, this is likely a good trade off.